# Xkb to replace § in the Slovak keyboard layout to ď/Ď

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to replace **§** in the Slovak keyboard layout (it's currently **'** - the first key to the right from my right pinky finger) on the English keyboard or keycode 48 on most keyboards) with the more frequently used **ď** letter. It's a letter you get when pressing shift and = and then the letter d.

From `xev -event keyboard` I get these values for each keypress:

left shift is keycode 50 and keysym 0xffe1

= is keycode 21 and keysym 0xfe5a

d is keycode 40 and keysym 0x64

Here is my xorg.conf.d (located in /usr/share/X11/xkb/)

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"

    Option "XkbLayout" "sk"
EndSection
```

What should I add to this file so I can press the key next to my right pinky finger and type the letter ď or Ď (with shift) instead of the current default §?

Comment: what distro and windowmanager or desktop environment are you using?  X11 or Wayland?  you're probably better off changing DE settings than the inputclass snippet you've shown, if there's an existing XKB option that does what you want.  see `man xkeyboard-config` for options and layouts.

Comment: I am in a command line for the most of my time. X11 of course. I use multiple DE - this is irrelevant Xkb is DE independent.